# Connecting to remote linux machine via python subprocess using PuTTY or plink throws error

Tags: python, linux, windows, ssh, putty

I am trying to execute few scripts in remote linux machine from windows host machine. I am hoping to achieve this using python subprocess +putty/plink.
When I try Putty or plink commands from windows cmd, it works fine. But if I try the same command using python subprocess, I get a lot of errors.

```
C:\Users\username>plink.exe username@machinename -pw password
```

Works fine. But when I try from python,

```
process = subprocess.Popen('plink.exe username@machinename -pw password'.split(),
                           env={'PATH':'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\'},
                           shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Throws the following error.

> Unable to open connection:
>
> gethostbyname: unknown error'

```
process = subprocess.Popen("putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw password -m C:\\script.sh machinename",
                           env={'PATH':'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\'},
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
                           ,shell=True);
```

> Unable to open connection:
>
> gethostbyname: unknown error'

I tried subprocess.check_ouput too with no luck.

```
output = subprocess.check_output("putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw password -m C:\\script.sh machinename", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
```

Throws the following error

> CalledProcessError: Command 'putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw
>   password -m C:\script.sh machinename' returned non-zero exit status 1

Could this be a firewall issue?

Comment: What happens if you don't reset the environment in the call to `Popen`?

Comment: Avoid using `shell=True` where possible, such as in this case. Maybe putty.exe returns a more useful exit code than the shell's exit code of "1" (fail).

Comment: Regarding `env`, generally you should modify `os.environ.copy()`. The docs clearly state what this parameter does: "If *env* is not `None`, it must be a mapping that defines the environment variables for the new process; these are used instead of the default behavior of inheriting the current process’ environment. *Note: If specified, `env` must provide any variables required for the program to execute. On Windows, in order to run a side-by-side assembly the specified `env`* **must** *include a valid `SystemRoot`.*" The crypto API also requires `SystemRoot`.

Comment: @alexis it does not recognize putty if I don't give the path. I get "putty is not recognizable internal or external error"

Comment: @eryksun If I don't use shell=True I get a strange "File not found" exception in Popen.

Comment: In that case you should not be zapping the PATH. You should be writing the full path for the command itself: `Popen(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" username@machinename etc.', ...)`

Comment: @alexis is correct. `Popen` calls `CreateProcess`, which uses the value of `PATH` in the current process to find the executable. When you use `shell=True`, then cmd.exe uses the `PATH` you give it. But you shouldn't be using the shell, and, as I said, you shouldn't be obliterating the environment passed to PuTTY, including `PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly advise against using PuTT or in general every external program to connect to shh and then interface with pipes.

Using the python library [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) this can be done much better.

For example:

```
# ... connect like one of the examples on github
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
```